# Bad review queue audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11294721) was found in the low quality review queue. Could be closed for a few reasons - I was planning on closing it for `Why doesn't this code work` but it could also easily be closed as `Too Broad`.

At the least, it should have been triaged. But nah, it's an audit. Yay.

I remember seeing a meta post a while back about reporting bad audit questions, so here I am.

Comment: "Why doesn't this code work" doesn't seem like an appropriate close reason to me. He's given the code that is being generated, explained what he wants to accomplish, and is asking how to do it. What more information should be provided?

Comment: Perhaps. `Any other idea? Ajax?` The question is asking, pretty blatantly, how to do dynamic DOM manipulation in Javascript. I think there are maybe one or two guides ([maybe more](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=insert+html+javascript)) on google regarding this topic.

Comment: What made this into an audit was the fact that it was a) old enough, b) had a score >= 5 and c) never got any DVs or CVs

Comment: It definitely isn't a "why doesn't this code work" question.  It may be too broad as phrased (and includes irrelevant background), but boiled down to "How can I replace all <widget> elements with the result of a web request when the page loads?" it's perfectly answerable.

Comment: Aren't audits supposed to be clear-cut examples of questions that are not closable?

Comment: I don't know enough of the technology discussed, but the only valid close reason for that question would be "too broad". That being said, the review audits are quite often terrible, nothing new there, they have been broken for ages. The only way to make it a priority for SO to fix them, is to stop doing reviews. The hundreds of meta posts about how broken they are have no effect.

Comment: @Magisch I believe anything that gets bandwagon up-voted to +5 or more can end up in the audit, no matter the actual quality. The meta effect seems to have lowered the score to +3 now, after the audit.

Comment: Some audits are bad. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Sobrique You mean, don't worry about it until you get incorrectly and automatically review-banned, because of bugs in the SO review audit system?

Comment: One bad review doesn't mean a review ban. It takes several. If the OP had picked up a review ban because of successive bad audits, I'd call that a problem.

Comment: @Sobrique "Well then why didn't you say something sooner?" could be something they'd say after successive bad audits.

Comment: FYI the LQPRQ only has answers in it now.  If you ever see an actual question it is always an audit.

Comment: @Sobrique The problem is that review bans are based upon Calendar time (to the best of my recollection).  So if you do a review a week, no problem.  If you are a more frequent reviewer, you could get a very high percentage correct but be tripped up by the bad audit examples.

Comment: Notice that not a single person decided to give advice on how to better ask the question, but immediately runs for the close button. The only comments on the question are 'I bet this is the problem' (which should be flagged anyway, given  the guessing nature of the comment). It's exactly this kind of nature that makes revisiting this site unattractive for brand new users. At the very least the expectation is to ask the op to elaborate, or refer them to the how to ask a good question page. Which nobody did.

Comment: @demongolem is actually a window (last X days) but I'm not sure if the cutoff is on the days or the hours, or a random 6-8 unit of time